# Avoid computing the same expression twice in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am using a function in a list comprehension and an if function:

```
new_list = [f(x) for x in old_list if f(x) !=0]
```

It annoys me that the expression `f(x)` is computed twice in each loop.

Is there a way to do it in a cleaner way? Something along the lines of storing the value or including the if statement at the beginning of the list comprehension.

Comment: maybe using just `for` loop?

Comment: `new_list = [computed for computed in [f(x) for x in old_list] if computed !=0]` - make a list of everything as an inner list, then filter in outer comprehension

Comment: To add to my comment above - put the inner in parentheses to make a generator (lazily evaluate, rather than store the whole inner list).

Comment: From python 3.8 onwards you could use `walrus` operator. `new_list = [y for x in old_list if (y := f(x))]
`

Comment: See [Python list comprehension - want to avoid repeated evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15812779/5166387)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compute the results beforehand and iterate over them

```
new_list = [x for x in map(f, old_list) if x !=0]
```

Moreover, since map computes the result per element when the element is accessed this is just one loop.

Comment: It's not the best idea to mix list comprehension and `map()`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There's two ways of processing list (*and other iterable data*): 1) list comprehension; 2) `map()`, `filter()` and `reduce()`. **Choose Your Side.** It's a bit confusing when you mix them into one expression. So it should be `new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, map(f, old_list)))` or `new_list = [x for x in [f(item) for item in old_list] if x != 0]`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght why would you need to 'choose a side' on this? these two concepts mix just fine! or do you have a counterexample? or is it a question of style to you (i could almost agree on that...)?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, yes, it's more about style. `map()` is part of functional approach of programming.

Answer (score 5):

you could use a generator expression (in order to avoid creating an unnecessary list) inside your list comprehension:

```
new_list = [fx for fx in (f(x) for x in old_list) if fx != 0]
```

---

starting from python 3.8 you will be able to do [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions):

```
new_list = [fx for x in old_list if (fx := f(x)) != 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

in Python 3.8 we'll have the ["walrus operator"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#simplifying-list-comprehensions) and be able to do just that!

```py
[y for x in old_list if (y := f(x)) != 0]
```

Comment: @gerrit noted, added an example

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `filter` to remove results:

```py
def f (x):
  return x * 2

old_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]

new_list = filter(lambda x: x != 0, [f(x) for x in old_list])

for x in new_list:
  print(x)
```

See it working [here.](https://repl.it/repls/WealthyCriminalNanotechnology)

Alternatively you could memoize the function so as to prevent ever having to compute the same result twice:

```py
def f (x):
  return x * 2

def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            print("Computing result for %s" % x)        
            memo[x] = f(x)
        return memo[x]
    return helper

memF = memoize(f)

old_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]

new_list = [memF(x) for x in old_list if memF(x) != 0]

for x in new_list:
  print(x)
```

Which is available [here.](https://repl.it/repls/FrankLemonchiffonFibonacci)