# walrus operator: if contition with strange results

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

i was playing around (in relation with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967363/avoid-computing-the-same-expression-twice-in-list-comprehension/56967555#56967555)) with the walrus operator `:=` which will be available in python 3.8.

with

```
def f(x):
    return x**3

old_list =  = list(range(9))
```

this works as expected (never mind that the example is pointless...):

```
new_list = [fx for x in old_list if (fx := f(x))  in {1, 8, 343}]
# [1, 8, 343]
```

this is valid and runs, but returns something unexpected:

```
new_list = [fx := f(x) for x in old_list if fx in {1, 8, 343}]
# []
```

what is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR your 2nd one is not "that" valid:

```
>>> old_list = list(range(9))
>>> f = lambda x: x ** 3
>>> [fx := f(x) for x in old_list if fx in {1, 8, 343}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'fx' is not defined
>>>
```

## Explanation

In your first list comprehension, `[fx for x in old_list if (fx := f(x))  in {1, 8, 343}]`, the `fx :=` creates a variable outside of it:

```
>>> old_list = list(range(9))
>>> f = lambda x: x ** 3
>>> [fx for x in old_list if (fx := f(x))  in {1, 8, 343}]
[1, 8, 343]
>>> fx
512
```

If you run `[fx := f(x) for x in old_list if fx in {1, 8, 343}]` afterwards, it will go like this:

- `for x in old_list` binds x to 0
- `if fx in {1, 8, 343}`, fx being the old `512` which is false
- as the if is false, the "select" (left) part is not executed, no call to f, no rebinding of fx, fx is still 512.
- assign x as the 2nd element of old_list, being 1
- ...

We can double check this interpretation like this:

```
>>> [print("no no no") for x in old_list if fx in {1, 8, 343}]
[]
```

`no no no` is never printed, so this side is never executed (as `fx` is 512, not in the `set`).

Comment: oh; `fx` had leaked to the global namespace (kept the interpreter open) that is why it looked like it was working! you are right!